# How to add probabilities values of a dataframe colunm, by categories, to a new column in the same dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm having a problem facing dataframes. I have, lets say, one dataframe with one column containing values (range 0 to 100000). An example:

```
                     TCGA.CG.4462
 ENSG00000000003       4.7574661
 ENSG00000000005       0.0000000
 ENSG00000000419       24.1066335
 ENSG00000000457       2.7631012
 ENSG00000000460       0.8928772
```

And I want to add a new column with the probabiliteis of the column data by the following 5 categories:

- non_expresed [0]
- low_expressed ]0,1]
- normal_expressed ]1,10]
- high_expressed [10,100]
- very_high_expressed > 100

So, for the example, the values that I want to add in a new column are:

- non_expresed: 0.2
- low_expressed 0.2
- normal_expressed: 0.4
- high_expressed: 0.2
- very_high_expressed: 0.0

So my dataframe becomes like this:

```
                     TCGA.CG.4462     Prob
 ENSG00000000003       4.7574661      0.4
 ENSG00000000005       0.0000000      0.2
 ENSG00000000419       24.1066335     0.2
 ENSG00000000457       2.7631012      0.4
 ENSG00000000460       0.8928772      0.2
```

I already tried a lot of different approaches, however, none have worked so far. I thought that the if conditions would be the best approach to resolve my problem, however, the if conditions gives error because length of condition is > 1.
Can anyone tell me whats the best approach to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use `cut` to find intervals and label them with the desired probabilities. Since, there are duplicates in the probabilities, warning message will appear, which can be ignored. See the demo below:

```
library(data.table)
cut(df1$TCGA.CG.4462, breaks = c(-Inf, 0, 1, 10, 100, Inf), include.lowest = TRUE)
# [1] (1,10]   [-Inf,0] (10,100] (1,10]   (0,1]   
# Levels: [-Inf,0] (0,1] (1,10] (10,100] (100, Inf]

df1[, prob := as.numeric(as.character(cut(TCGA.CG.4462, 
                                          breaks = c(-Inf, 0, 1, 10, 100, Inf), 
                                          include.lowest = TRUE,
                                          labels = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.0))))]

# Warning message:
#   In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) 
#                 else paste0(labels,  : duplicated levels in factors are deprecated

df1
#              genes TCGA.CG.4462 prob
# 1: ENSG00000000003    4.7574661  0.4
# 2: ENSG00000000005    0.0000000  0.2
# 3: ENSG00000000419   24.1066335  0.2
# 4: ENSG00000000457    2.7631012  0.4
# 5: ENSG00000000460    0.8928772  0.2
```

**with base R (no package used)**

```
df1 <- within(df1, prob <- as.numeric(as.character(cut(TCGA.CG.4462, 
                                                       breaks = c(-Inf, 0, 1, 10, 100, Inf), 
                                                       include.lowest = TRUE,
                                                       labels = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.0)))))
```

**Data:**

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- fread('ENSG00000000003       4.7574661
             ENSG00000000005       0.0000000
             ENSG00000000419       24.1066335
             ENSG00000000457       2.7631012
             ENSG00000000460       0.8928772', header = F)
colnames(df1) <- c("genes", "TCGA.CG.4462")
```

**EDIT: Third column: adds value 1 to "third" column**

**data.table package**

```
df1[, `:=` ( prob = as.numeric(as.character(cut(TCGA.CG.4462, 
                                          breaks = c(-Inf, 0, 1, 10, 100, Inf), 
                                          include.lowest = TRUE,
                                          labels = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.0)))),
             third = 1)]
```

**base R:**

```
within(df1, c(prob <- as.numeric(as.character(cut(TCGA.CG.4462, 
                                              breaks = c(-Inf, 0, 1, 10, 100, Inf), 
                                              include.lowest = TRUE,
                                              labels = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.0)))),
       third <- 1))
```

Comment: Thanks Sathish! It isindeed a good approach and work just fine!

Comment: Is it possible to add a third column with the respective categorie using a similar approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another  `data.table` solution which uses a *lookup table* and *updates in a non-equi join*:

```
library(data.table)
# create lookup table
lookup <- data.table(
  expression = c("non", "low", "normal", "high", "very_high"),
  Prob = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.0),
  lower = c(-Inf, 0, 10^(0:2))
)
lookup[, upper := shift(lower, type = "lead", fill = Inf)][]
```

> ```
>    expression Prob lower upper
> 1:        non  0.2  -Inf     0
> 2:        low  0.2     0     1
> 3:     normal  0.4     1    10
> 4:       high  0.2    10   100
> 5:  very_high  0.0   100   Inf
> ```

```
# update in a non-equi join
# note the left open intervals
setDT(DT)[lookup, on = .(TCGA.CG.4462 > lower, TCGA.CG.4462 <= upper), 
   `:=`(expression = expression, Prob = Prob)][]
```

> ```
>             row.id TCGA.CG.4462 expression Prob
> 1: ENSG00000000003    4.7574661     normal  0.4
> 2: ENSG00000000005    0.0000000        non  0.2
> 3: ENSG00000000419   24.1066335       high  0.2
> 4: ENSG00000000457    2.7631012     normal  0.4
> 5: ENSG00000000460    0.8928772        low  0.2
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
  "row.id                TCGA.CG.4462
 ENSG00000000003       4.7574661
  ENSG00000000005       0.0000000
  ENSG00000000419       24.1066335
  ENSG00000000457       2.7631012
  ENSG00000000460       0.8928772"
)
```